# Multiple svn repositories on linux Ubuntu with plesk

Tags: linux, svn, ubuntu, plesk, vhosts

I have a linux vserver and a domain "mydomain".I already have an working svn and trac system, but a liitle problem with multiple repositories.

my repositorie path is :

```
/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/svn/repo1
```

and

```
/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/svn/folder/repo2
/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/svn/folder/repo3
/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/svn/folder/repo4
```

now I want to connect through https: this already working for repo1, but not for the others.Actually my vhost_ssl.conf is under 
/var/www/vhosts/svn.mydomain.com/conf/ as a subdomain.with my vhost.conf :

```
  1<Location /svn>
  2    DAV svn
  3    SVNParentPath /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/svn/
  4    AuthType Basic
  5    AuthName "My Repository"
  6    AuthUserFile /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/svn/svn.password
  7    Require valid-user
  8 </Location>
```

so i can reach svn through https://svn.mydomain.com/svn/repo1

What should I do, to get following:
1.Reach repo 1 with https://svn.mydomain.com/repo1

2.Reach repo2 .. repo4 through
`https://svn.mydomain.com/repoX` ?

Answer (score 1):

**Point 1**

Repo in root will have some troubles for the rest of non-svn part of site under root (can't recall exact URL(s) to the discussion here, on SF, but you can try to find - they have svn-related tag(s), "Location /" in body and at least one my answer)

**Point 2**

With /folder/ for repo[234] path you can't have common for repo1 and these repos SVNParentPath'ed Location (without additional tricks in Apache config - /svn and /folder pathes must be equivalent)

**Point 3**

`SVNPath` *can be* used for totally unrelated by path repositories, but every SVNPath **must be** inside unique Location

```
<Location /repo1>
    DAV svn
    SVNPath /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/svn/repo1
    ...
</Location>
<Location /repo2>
    DAV svn
    SVNPath /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/svn/folder/repo2
    ...
</Location>
```